# call a function on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Login Form Validation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script>
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.myval = 5;

    $scope.ctrlClickHandler = function(){
        alert("Inside controller: value of myval is " + $scope.myval);
    }       
};

var globalClickHandler=function globalClickHandler(){
    alert("Inside global click handler ");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main" ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form id="form_id" method="get" name="myform">
<label>User Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<button type="button" ng-click="ctrlClickHandler()">Login</button>
</form></div></div></body></html>
```

this is my above code and i am unable to call the ctrlClickHandler method . i dont knwo where i am wrong. could any one please help to me on it.
Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle which replicates the issue?

Comment: your code does work correctly. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aa64psL/)

Comment: oh create just i checked and it worked in fiddle env. but not working in crome

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the `angular.module` inorder to work with angular

```js
var globalClickHandler=function globalClickHandler(){
    alert("Inside global click handler ");
}

angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", MyCtrl)

 function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.myval = 5;

    $scope.ctrlClickHandler = function(){
        alert("Inside controller: value of myval is " + $scope.myval);
    }       
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form id="form_id" method="get" name="myform">
<label>User Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<button type="button" ng-click="ctrlClickHandler()">Login</button>
</form></div>
```

Comment: thanks you so much  @ sachila to fixed this. its work and its would help to me for next step..

Comment: no problem. make sure to check as answer if this helped